# MacBook Pro Admin User

Tags: user-accounts, administrator, macbook-pro

My login credentials had an "Admin" Account status on my MacBook Pro but after resetting the password, it got replaced to "Standard". Now I can't seem to change it back to the Admin credentials. I can't even restart because it says only an administrator can close other user sessions. Any guidance on how to change this?

Comment: You can always force restart by long-pressing the power button. Do you have access to other Admin account?

Comment: Asked & answered on Ask Different - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/164332/85275 Once you have a new admin account, you can restore the privileges to your existing one from there.

Comment: No, apparently no account had Admin privileges. I ended up finally going to the Apple Store and have a "Genius" perform some workaround. Interestingly, if I had waited a week, I would've known that I could've logged into the root without a password (recent Apple security issue) and resolved my issue that way...